# Select with mouse on a PDF (User Input)

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, pdfbox

I'm currently using PDFBox and I'm trying to open a PDF so that the user can select with his mouse areas to crop, I've no idea how to proceed to make a PDF viewer & let the user input the selected rectangle to crop.

PDPage#setCropBox(PDRectangle cropBox)

https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.html#setCropBox(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle)
https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/common/PDRectangle.html

The only thing I'm missing here is how the user can decide to which point he wants to crop (and I'm thinking of a mouse selection & so having the view of the PDF to select which area to crop), otherwise if he inputs random values, it won't be accurate.

```java
package uk.mushow.pdftoexcel;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PDFToExcel extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("PDF Test");

        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        final Button openButton = new Button("Select pdf");

        openButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            configureFileChooser(fileChooser);
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    openFile(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        final GridPane inputGridPane = new GridPane();

        GridPane.setConstraints(openButton, 0, 1);
        inputGridPane.setHgap(6);
        inputGridPane.setVgap(6);
        inputGridPane.getChildren().add(openButton);

        final Pane rootGroup = new VBox(60);
        rootGroup.getChildren().add(inputGridPane);
        rootGroup.setPadding(new Insets(60, 60, 60, 60));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootGroup));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void configureFileChooser(final FileChooser fileChooser) {
        fileChooser.setTitle("pdf selector");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF", "*.pdf"));
    }

    private void openFile(File file) throws IOException {
        PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(file);
        //This is where I don't know how to handle the file
        PDPage pdPage = pdDocument.getPage(0);
        //Need the user to select his own cropbox but can't be just values from his head otherwise it wouldn't be accurate);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: ADDED IMAGE

[How would a user know the coordinates to select that green rectangle?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tRlg.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra sorry I'm new to this, I added the code, I'm trying to figure out how the user can know the exact cropbox values

Comment: Thank you for your comment @KJ. I wanted to do that in the first place (always a rectangle to be cropped), to ask the coordinates, but how can a user, know the EXACT coordinates of the rectangle on the PDF they want to crop. It's values so it'd mostly be random & not precise, and I don't know how the values work, would you have a background in that field that you could help me out on that or explaining how can a user calculate the exact coordinates? Thanks.

Comment: I added the image so you can see what I mean. How could someone that load a PDF on the app, select that precise location (which can vary from different files), without the mouse selection only coordinates.

Comment: PDFBox PDFDebugger shows the PDF coordinates when you move the mouse. Maybe you can use the sources as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for getting co-ordinates in most pdf view/annotators is by adding a highlight. and that usually provides some user feed back so the top left of this rescaled example is 45 mm from the left and 111.7mm down from the top (however that alone is not the full picture since the real units have been converted to mm so you need to export the highlight data into a different set of units, which a different viewer may use. Both are corrrect but just showing the values via different outputs.

[image]

[image]

You need to "Square" up those differences and an export of comments usually does that, however the maths can be a challenge as its done in PDF page co-ordinates.

```
    "rect": [
      227.495148,
      351.695496,
      386.449585,
      430.445496
    ],
    "subtype": "Popup",
    "annotationType": 16,
    "parentType": "Square",
    "parentId": "6R",
    "parentRect": [
      128.322571,
      24.175232,
      210.179276,
      485.779327
    ],
```

You will need to experiment with your chosen libraries as to which is easiest, personally for my uses, I would look towards milking command line utilities to do the maths and text output for me.